# New to Python (3.4.3), trying to pip install basic libraries and receiving this message

Tags: python, windows

`Command "C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Jamey\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-4xxi4hts\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Jamey\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-l8qukpar-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failedwith error code 1 in C:\Users\Jamey\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4xxi4hts\numpy`

It has a lot of errors, do I need to add some basic libaries before installing more advance ones? Also tells me I need Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0

Answer (score 0):

For numpy and other such libraries, these are difficult to build on Windows because they need to be compiled during installation. Setting up a proper build environment is difficult on Windows.

You have a few choices:

1. Download a build of Python that includes these libraries. A popular package of Python that includes numpy (and other scientific libraries) is [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/). The [scipy download page](http://www.scipy.org/install.html) lists some more options for you.
2. Download pre-compiled binaries for Windows. These are available as standard Windows installers. For example [here is a link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.2/) to the downloads for numpy 1.9 (you can download the Windows installer from there).
3. A list of pre-compiled Python modules for Windows is [available here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). I suggest you bookmark that page and when you have trouble installing something on Windows, chances are it will be listed there.

If you are downloading packages, make sure you download for the right version of Python. If there are two versions (a 64 bit and a 32 bit) available, **this refers to the version of *Python* not Windows** that you have installed.